# Story of ancient coin with chariot and atomic mushroom cloud on it

Tags: story-identification, comics, tv, novella

I heard this summary from a friend when I was in 7th grade in the 1970s.

Some archeologists find a near-prehistoric coin that has the image of a man driving a chariot in profile and in the background is the familiar mushroom cloud of a atomic explosion.

The two archeologists wonder if the ancients did have thermonuclear weapons. The story then shifts to two engineers puzzling over how to built a giant crossbow that could hurl bombs more efficiently than missiles. The end.

I have searched and searched and the friend moved away into parts unknown long ago.

I thought it was on old Night Gallery television series. But no. A comic book? Could be.

Been asking around for decades. If you can get this you are truly amazing.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE! That's a great first post; don't hesitate to add any details if you remember them.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd paragraphs remind me of a book by Erich von Daniken: Chariots of the Gods --- where he concludes that in ancient wars that have since become myths, the people were visited by aliens and given the equivalent of atomic bombs, which caused the mythical destruction in our legends. But archaeologists?

Comment: Well. I think I found it myself if anyone is interested. It's a five page story in a 1970 Creepy magazine #38 titled "Sticks And Stones To Break Their Bones" and this has to be it. Except it's a tablet instead of a coin and a catapult instead of a giant crossbow. If you can get by the ax maniac on the cover it can be found with a little difficulty at the Internet Archive. Kinda cute. Could have sworn I looked through all the Creepy mags decades ago. Ah well.

Comment: @RexEricEngstrom want to make an answer out of it?

Answer (score 4):

After digging up the archive link and reading the PDF, I would agree that the story fits most of the items listed in the original question.

It is in [Creepy Magazine #38](https://archive.org/details/warrencreepy-038), by Warren Publishing, March of 1971. Story by Stu Schwartzburg, "Sticks and Stones to Break Their Bones" is the title.

The protagonist has several curios depicting things out of time. An American Indian with an M-1 rifle, a caveman with a machine gun and a chariot on a tablet with an atomic explosion and planes engaged in a dogfight.

He has a realization, and takes his artifacts and stories to the Pentagon, and barges into the war room where they are discussing the "newest greatest weapon". He posits his theory that when mankind gets close to destroying itself, a force goes through and destroys/removes all their advanced weapons.

The general throws him out as a crackpot, and they go back to discussing the latest, greatest weapon, a rock throwing catapult.